# raw_input() in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

A question from my reading of **Learn Python The Hard Way**:

```
y = raw_input("Name? ")
```

puts the result into variable y.

Then on line 9 in the following code, **raw_input("?")**, where does the result go?

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it simply, it doesn't get stored - control-C (`^C`) gets the interpreter to stop doing what it's doing, and exits. If you type anything else at the question mark (and of course press `Enter`), the program will run. The `raw_input` is there only to wait for user input.

Comment: Note that "anything" won't necessarily cause the program to continue; the program will only regain control when the input is terminated with `Enter`.

Answer (score 1):

The input is not stored. Here `raw_input` is used for the purpose of confirmation, so the value of the input is irrelevant; the program is only concerned with waiting until either <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `raw_input("?")` represent something like `Press any key to continue`

In non-interactive mode _ has no special meaning.

The python interpreter understands "_" as a reference to the last value it
computed, the input is stored in a special variable `_`

```
In [83]: raw_input("Enter : ")
Enter : Hi There
Out[83]: 'Hi There'

In [84]: _
Out[84]: 'Hi There'
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `_`. Although it never actually gets used in the program.

Comment: That's only true when the interpreter is run interactively.  It's not true in general, and if the OP adds `print _` to his code and runs it, the result will be a `NameError`.

Comment: @DSM and the normal caveat applies using `_` when it's common for `gettext` and co...